# JMX Manage beans from HTTP

Tags: java, spring, jmx, mbeans

I have a Spring application, and I have enabled JMX for some beans. For each beans, at least, I have a get operation and a set operation. I have read a little about Jolokia, and it provides an HTTP bridge between you and JMX. It provides a way to sent GET requests to read the value of managed beans, and POST request to set them as well.

I'm wondering if, either Jolokia ships with a way to autogenerate a web page, where you can read/write your managed beans from, or if there is already a tool for this.

For example, let's say Jolokia has this capability. So then, if you go, per say, to localhost:8080/jolokia/dashboard, you will see an autogenerated web page like this:

beanName1: vaue1 EditButton1
beanName2: vaue2 EditButton2
.
.
beanNameN: valueN EditButtonN

I think it can be such a nice tool, and it can be autogenerated. VisualVM does this in a great way, but in a HTTP world basis, it could be really good to monitor your application from your Mobile anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want just a simple web ui for jmx management, have a look at https://github.com/lbovet/jminix

Comment: Thanks. I responded myself a couple hours ago, pointing to the same page ;).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this by using [JMinix](https://github.com/lbovet/jminix/wiki)